# How to remove files and personal information from computer?

Tags: hard-drive, security, formatting, advanced-format, file-shredding

I'm about to give my computer to a lab for repair. I'd like first to remove personal info like browsing history, software installed, various files.

Some of the files I want removed, I accidently already moved to extrnal hard drive, so I can't use a shredded to specifiy them for removal.

Should I use http://www.fileshredder.org/ and go to "Shred Free Disk Space"? can this some how damage the disk performance?

what about removing browsing history and so?

Comment: What kind of repair? If it doesn't involve the disk just remove it ...

Comment: it's an ultrabook, and it does involve it, I'm returning it back as DOA.

Comment: Reinstall the OS, then erase free space using cipher in windows.....https://www.pcworld.com/article/2464163/how-to-securely-overwrite-deleted-files-with-a-built-in-windows-tool.html

Answer (score 0):

If this is an SSD, then you don't need to do anything.

For an HDD,
if you are worried about outsiders recovering your deleted data,
a better utility is the free
[Sysinternals SDelete](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete),
using the `-c` parameter, since it will also clean out the *names*
of the deleted files in the MFT (Master File Table).

Comment: yes it's SSD, can you explain why shouldn't I worry? are all shredding programs not relevant at all for SSD?

Comment: An SSD uses [Trim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_%28computing%29) to delete data, which erases the contents of the deleted block on the disk. This will not delete the *names* of the deleted files, so in case this worries you go ahead and use SDelete. Normally writing that much to an SSD is frowned upon, since it shortens the lifetime of the disk, but in the case of a DOA computer this shouldn't matter much.

Comment: I don't mind the filenames . that's interesting. so it harder for goverment/labs for example to restore file on an SSD? didn't know that.

Comment: It's impossible as far as I know, as the erasure is done electrically and is final